# New user can Select on all schemas without granting any permissions or assigning roles

Tags: sql, azure

In an Azure SQL database, I'm setting up new database contained users that are intended to have Select permissions on a specific schema

When I have created the new user, before assigning any role or granting any permissions, the new user has Select rights to all schemas in the database.

I've checked the Public role to ensure there are no Select permissions they are inheriting, but these are still set to the default sys objects.

To test I also set up a new Azure SQL database, and created a test schema and table. Then I created a new user in this database, and as expected, this user could not see the test schema and table without specifically granting access.

Is there some database setting that I'm missing somewhere that could be allowing these rights by default?

Answer (score 0):

1. In Azure SQL, there are different types of roles and permissions for each user. If the user is added to a particular group, then he will have those permissions to query the set of applications he is part of. To get rid of this, the user needs to be a part of group which doesn’t have any application access or special permissions
2. Once user is added to the database, we need to grant the user permissions to query or to do any action on the database.

You can try this

1. in the master database we need to create **LOGIN**
2. `create login [MyLogin]  with password =  'Not1My2Real3Password'`

Now we are moving to the permissions which you want to give your **LOGIN/User**. Here are some options for example

1. if you want the user to be able to create databases,  then  in the master database
2. `exec sp_addRoleMember 'dbmanager',  'MyUser';`
3. if you want the user to be able to create other **LOGIN**,  then  in the master database
4. `exec sp_addRoleMember 'loginmanager',  'MyUser'`
5. in each individual database, that you want to give the **USER** full control in the database level, grant him db_owner
6. `exec sp_addRoleMember 'db_owner',  'MyUser';`

Note! Give the **USER** only the permission that he need and nothing more! The above is only a sample of a few permissions. Use **GRANT** to give permissions on specific entities in the database and don't make each USER a database owner.